# Classic ASP website displays in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have not dealt with classic ASP for over 13 years (and IIS and ASP.NET for a while as well) and today I had to move a classic ASP website to a new server - Windows 2012 with IIS 8.5 from Windows Server 2003 with IIS6. I copied the website directory onto one of the drives (the same drive letter as it was on the old server) and went to IIS Manager and created an application for that directory.

Locally I can access the application via http://localhost/AppAlias/Default.asp and it renders in IE but when I access it remotely via http://ServerName/AppAlias/Default.asp, it does not rende rin IE, instead I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error. When I open the same URL in Chrome, it renders just like it does when accessed locally.

I checked IIS settings on the server for ASP applications and under Basic Settings I clicked on Test Settings. Authentication uses Pass-through and it seemed fine but authorization had a warning mark on it. The message was "Cannot verify access to path E:\Pages\Test\AppAlias" and in details I found the following:

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the
>       specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. 
>       Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, 
>       and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ 
>       has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

I gave Network Service read access but still having an issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: Disable `Show Friendly Error Messages` under `Advanced` tab in `Internet Options` in Internet Explorer, to see what actual error the server is sending back.

Comment: I did but nothing has changed

Comment: Try opening the web page on the server in IE directly using the IP address instead of domain name (example: http://10.x.x.x/AppAlias/Default.asp instead of http://ServerName/AppAlias/Default.asp). We have to do this on our servers from time to time as well.

That said though it doesn't really sound like a site/code issue if it renders fine in other browsers. If it were you should get the same result in all browsers.

Comment: Just curious, if you create a test HelloWorld.asp file with a simple Response.Write in it, does this work in both? At least you'll establish if it's code-related or not...